# Does Groovy's ternary conditional operator have a bug in string expressions?

Tags: groovy, expression, conditional-operator

Groovy's ternary condition operator has a very strange behavior in this code:

```java
def f = true
println 'a' + f?'b':'z' + 'c'   // b

f = false
println 'a' + f?'b':'z' + 'c'   // b
```

It prints b in both cases and ignores the other two strings without warning! Is that a bug in the Groovy compiler?

If numbers are used, in the place of strings, an error is generated:

```java
def f = true
println 1 + f?2:3 + 3           // Error: Cannot find matching method int#plus(boolean).
```

Parenthesis fix the problem:

```java
def f = true
println 'a' + (f?'b':'z') + 'c' // abc
println 1 + (f?2:3) + 3         // 6
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: I think Groovy is evaluating it as `('a' + f) ?'b':('z' + 'c')`. You should use parentheses (I think you expect it to be evaluated as `'a' + (f?'b':'z') + 'c'`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all to do with operator precedence.

Most* languages have a rule of precedence for operators (which ones are taken first when there are multiple options).  [Groovys order can be found here](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_operator_precedence).

As you can see, `+` comes in at position 5, but ternary comes in at a lowly 14

This mean that Groovy parses your expression as (added brackets to show):

```
('a' + f) ? 'b' : ('z' + 'c')
```

Which when you fill in the variables, becomes

```
('atrue') ? 'b' : ('zc')
```

In groovy, any non empty (and non null) String is considered `true` when taken as a boolean, so the result of the above is `b`

As you've seen, the answer is to add parentheses to show the parser what you actually want

(* Lisps, Forth and probably more don't )

Comment: Changed "All languages" to "Most languages", as some don't require operator precedence)